# python code with mulitprocessing only spawns one process each time

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a simple python code, trying to convert a batch of jpg file to png. But this code only spawn one subprocess each time on my linux machine, what's the problem with this code?

```
from scipy.misc import imread, imsave
from multiprocessing import Process, util
import logging

util.log_to_stderr(level=logging.DEBUG)
def imgcvt(inf, outf):
    im=imread(inf)
    imsave(outf,im)

for i in range(3):
    run_list = [];
    threads = [];
    for j in range(1,21):
        fn = str(i*20+j+1)
        run_list.append((fn+".jpg", fn+".png"))
    for dev in run_list:
        proc = Process(target=imgcvt, args=dev)
        proc.start()
        proc.join()
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `proc.join()` after starting every process means you are waiting for it to terminate before continuing.

Instead, you should store all `Process` objects to a list, and then join on all of them:

```
processes = []
for dev in run_list:
    proc = Process(target=imgcvt, args=dev)
    proc.start()
    processes.append(proc)
for proc in processes:
    proc.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `multiprocessing.Pool` object. It starts a few processes, then converts your images in parallel until they're all done.  It's nice because it's easy to control, and returns information from every function back to the original caller.

### source

```
import multiprocessing, time

def convert( (inpath,outpath) ):
    if 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        print 'convert:',inpath,outpath
    else:
        im = imread(inpath)
        imsave(outpath, im)
    return outpath

if __name__=='__main__':
    run_list = []
    for j in range(5):
        fn = str(j+1)
        run_list.append( (fn+".jpg", fn+".png") )

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()   # one Process per CPU
    print pool.map(convert, run_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()                 # wait for all jobs to finish
```

### output

```
convert: 3.jpg 3.png
convert: 2.jpg 2.png
convert: 4.jpg 4.png
convert: 1.jpg 1.png
convert: 5.jpg 5.png
['1.png', '2.png', '3.png', '4.png', '5.png']
```